# Firefox bug on ToolkitScriptManager and AsyncFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, firefox

I haven't encountered any problem so far on my application while using IE7+ and Google Chrome until I discovered that one of my module has a bug in my ToolkitScriptManager when using Mozilla Firefox.

The best way to understand the error is to show a screen shot:

[image]

This is the very first time I saw this error. I tried debugging this by replacing `ajax:ToolkitScriptManager` to `asp:ScriptManager` and I think it has something to do with `AsyncFileUpload` but I can't pinpoint where and how.

**This error is specific only to Firefox.**

If you need more info, just comment below. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the width of the AsyncFileUpload control using css:

Follow below Steps:

- Apply CssClass on ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload like
  "imageUploaderField"
- Write `Css(".imageUploaderField input{width:100%!important;}")`

If the result is the same, update your ajax toolkit with the latest
    edition.

References:

- [AsyncFileUpload with Firefox 22.0b1](http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/27429)

If it still doesn't work then it could be a Firefox bug.

Comment: Let me try this sir @ work 'coz I am currently at home. I'll give you a feedback as soon as I have tried this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why you have to include the css class. Nevertheless, it works!.=D I want to update the answer for better understanding.

Comment: Yeah i thought it was crazy too that it had anything to do with the problem in the first place but anyways, glad to know that it works. Feel free to update the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do you have some huge javascript under execution?, this may be a cause as it happened once to a colleage where he was looking 1Million*1Million times and was getting the same error.

Try to find out any piece of code that is taking too long..

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I got it working right now with @Sriniva answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the latest version of ajaxtoolkit it will fix this bug